# Browser Integrity Check - NGINX

Tags: http, nginx, proxy, web, webserver

So I have made a NGINX HTTP Reverse Proxy, and want to have a js browser integrity check on it.
Like the following:
http://prntscr.com/a1rnve
http://prntscr.com/a1rnyf

Can someone direct me on how to go about this?
Been trying for hours and can't do it.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/eA8tut60
I have been using  a PHP script I made. This was effective, but as the attacks got bigger, the cpu usage lags out the game.
I found out that the xhosts.uk HTTP Proxy uses a nginx reverse proxy - http://185.61.137.60/

How would I achieve something like this?

Answer (score 0):

In that case, the website you're trying to access to is using CloudFlare anti dDos protection. I would recommend it, read more [here](https://www.cloudflare.com/ddos/) :)